# How to insert data into mysql with dynamic form like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

[this my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys4mW.png)

My form code:

```html
<script src="dist/css/style.css"></script>
<script src="dist/js/choosen.js"></script>

<?php
include "../site.php";
include "../db=connection.php";

$queryjob = "SELECT * FROM jobdesk";
$rsjob=mysqli_query($con,$queryjob);


echo "<div class='content-wrapper'>

 <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-12'>
            <div class='card'>
              <div class='card-header'>
                <h3 class='card-title'>INPUT JOB DESCRIPTION STAFF</h3>
                <div class='card-tools'>
                  <div class='input-group input-group-sm' style='width: 150px;'>
                    <input type='text' name='table_search' class='form-control float-right' placeholder='Search'>
                    
                    <div class='input-group-append'>
                      <button type='submit' onclick='reloadsalary(0,0,0)' class='btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-arrow-left'></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class='card-body table-responsive p-0'>


              <div class='card card-primary' style='height:700px;'>
              
              <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class='card-body'>
                 <div class='form-group' >
                    <label>STAFF</label>
                    <select class='chosen' name='staff' id='staff' onchange='getstaff(this.value)' class='form-control'>
                    <option selected='selected' value=0>Pilihan</option>";

                    while($rowjob = mysqli_fetch_array($rsjob)){
                      echo "<option value='".$rowjob['id']."'>".$rowjob['nama']."</option>";
                    }
                    echo"</select>
                  </div>
                  <div class=form-group' name='divstaff' id='divstaff'>";
                  echo "</div>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' id='but_upload'>Submit</button>";
              echo" 
            </div>        
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>";
?>
<script>
   function getstaff(x) {
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'getSalary.php',
      data:{'staff':x},
      success:function(data){
        $('#divstaff').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chosen").chosen();
    $("#but_upload").click(function(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var a = document.getElementById("staff").options[document.getElementById("staff").selectedIndex].value;
        var h = "";
      for (var i = 1; i <= $("#salaryItem").val(); i++) {
        if(i==1){
          h = h + $("#keterangan"+i).val();
        }
        else{
          h = h + ";" + $("#keterangan"+i).val();
        }
      }

        fd.append('staff',a);
        fd.append('keterangan',h);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'insertSalary.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
             if(response=="success"){
                alert(response);
              reloadPage(-13,0,0);
             }
            },
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

`getsalary.php`:

The following code is get salary.php and there are some problems when sending with Ajax

```html
<?php
include "../site.php";
include "../db=connection.php";

$queryjob = "SELECT * FROM jobdesk WHERE id=".$_POST['staff'];
$rsjob=mysqli_query($con,$queryjob);

while($rowjob = mysqli_fetch_array($rsjob)){
      $data= explode(",",$rowjob['job']);
      for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++){
          echo " <div class=form-group'>
            <label style='margin-right:85px;'><option value=".$data[$i].">".$data[$i]."</option></label>
                <select name='salaryItem".$i."' id='salaryItem".$i."' onchange='getSalaryItem(this.value,".$i.")'>
                   <option selected='selected' value=0>Pilih jumlah Item</option>";
      
                          for ($x = 1; $x <= 20; $x++){
                            echo "<option value=".$x.">".$x."</option>";
                          }

                echo "</select>
                </div></br>
                <div class=form-group' name='divsalary".$i."' id='divsalary".$i."'></div>";

                  echo"
                  </div>";
                                    }  
                  }
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".chosen").chosen();
})

function getSalaryItem(x,y){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'getSalary_item.php',
      data:{'salaryItem':x,'countItem':y},
      success:function(data){
        $('#divsalary'+y).html(data);
      }
    });
    
  } 
</script>
```

`salary_item.php`:

```html
<?php
 include "../site.php";
 include "../db=connection.php";

 $jobdesk = $_POST['jenisgaji'];
 $jd = $_POST['jd'];

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM jenisgaji WHERE id_job=".$jobdesk;
$rs3=mysqli_query($con,$query3);
//$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs3);

 for ($x = 1; $x <= $jd; $x++){
  //$query4 = "SELECT * FROM ketSal WHERE jenisgaji LIKE '%".$jobdesk."%' and flag = 1";
  //$rs4=mysqli_query($con,$query4);
  echo"<div class=form-group' style='margin-bottom:10px;'>
     <label>Job Item ".$x."</label>
     <input type='textbox' required class='form-control' name='".$jd."keterangan".$x."' id='".$jd."keterangan".$x."' placeholder='Ketikkan Keterangan Job disini'>
     </input>
  <!---- <select class='chosen' name='keterangan".$x."' id='keterangan".$x."' style='width: 100%;'>
  <option selected='selected' value=0>Pilihan</option> --->";

 
  echo"</select></div>";

 }

 ?>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".chosen").chosen();
  });
 </script>
```

[image]

Comment: have you get any error in console? or proper data not passed in ajax

Comment: yeah i get some errors on the console, like this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at b (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.dataFilter (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.k._evalUrl (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ie (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: can you put console error here

Comment: error like the picture above

Comment: are you access external page?

Comment: yeah, i access the getsallary.php page and getsalary_item.php

Comment: is sallary.php and getSallary_item.php in same folder

Comment: Can you share me website url?

Comment: yeah in same folder

Comment: www.2canholiday.com

Comment: send me url where sallary.php  use

Comment: https://www.2canholiday.com/Admin/FormInsertSallary2.php, the url in admin

Comment: It showing 404 page

Comment: If admin you can send me admin details in my email.My email id "jscatoz@gmail.com"